# How can I log in to Yahoo FInance using Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, yahoo-finance

I've tried the following way, but every time I click on the "Next" button in the [login](https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.src=finance&.intl=us&.lang=en-US&.done=https%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fquotes%2Flogin%2Fview%2Fv1%2F), chromdriver would open a new tab and redirect me to [this page](https://subscriptions.yahoo.com/products/norton-security-online?ncid=dcm_268575827_461535665_127172993).

```
from selenium import webdriver

path = "https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.src=finance&.intl=us&.lang=en-US&.done=https%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fquotes%2Flogin%2Fview%2Fv1%2F"
option = webdriver.Chrome()
option.add_argument("--incognito")
option.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
browser = webdriver.Chrome("/path/to/chromedriver", optiont=option)
browser.get(path)
browser.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("username")

# all three attempts below redirected me to the page mentioned above
browser.find_element_by_name("signin").click()
browser.find_element_by_class_name("button-container").click()
browser.find_element_by_id("login-username-form").click()
```

I wonder this is some kind of secutiy they have considering the redirected page.

I also tried sending password in the `hidden-input-container`

```
browser.find_element_by_name("passwd").send_keys("password")
```

to get `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable` error. I guess I need to press the Next button before sending the password.

I'd much appreciate any help on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

path = "https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.src=finance&.intl=us&.lang=en-US&.done=https%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fquotes%2Flogin%2Fview%2Fv1%2F"
option = Options()
option.add_argument("--incognito")
option.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver",options=option)
browser.get(path)
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"username"))).send_keys("validusername")
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"signin"))).click()
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"password"))).send_keys("password")
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"login-signin"))).click()
```

Browser snapshot:

[image]

Comment: It worked, and it stopped working... Why would that be? Typically this line: 

WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"signin"))).click()

stopped working and started to redirect me to the security webpage. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @anton-sturluson : No idea why treating like this.Its working for me.

Comment: @anton-sturluson : add this option to check if you can get rid of that `option.add_argument("--disable-web-security")`

Comment: This is really bugging me, but adding that option doesn't work. One weird thing I noticed is that once
browser.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("username")

stopped working, I tried 
browser.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("username@gmail.com")

, and this worked for a few trials and now it stopped working again...

Comment: I would request check your security of windows/linux whichever os you are using.Seems its not a problem of selenium otherwise I would have received the same error.

Comment: for some reason this clicks on the ad when i run instead of the login button